# Theorical efficiency of Chirped Pulse Amplification HB11 fusion reaction

Tags: fusion, cold-fusion

I read that scientists finally reproduced a [more efficient](https://newatlas.com/energy/hb11-hydrogen-boron-fusion-clean-energy/) fusion with a novel approach.

**They accelerate hydrogen inside a pellet with a LASER. A single H atom produces three $\text{He-4}^+$ nuclei**.

If employed directly, 3 nuclei means 3 x $1.602 \times 10^{-19}$ Coulomb of charge. So we need to **keep $0.2081^{19}$ hydrogen atoms reacting every second to have a constant output of 1 Ampere.**

The question that bugs me is, how many Amperes are necessary to accelerate that many H atoms within the boron using the Chirped Pulse Amplification laser to keep them reacting?